# WARNING: index 'indexer_name': dict=keywords and prefixes and morphology enabled, forcing index_exact_words=1

Tags: sphinx

How to remove below warning?

```
WARNING: index 'indexer_name': dict=keywords and prefixes and morphology enabled, forcing index_exact_words=1
```

Please help me. I am new to Sphinx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its telling you **don't** have `index_exact_words=1` in your index config. So its added it anyway.

If you added to `index_exact_words=1` the index, wouldnt get the warning :)

Comment: True Sphinx master. Just 1 thing, will adding (index_exact_words=1) it impact on existing system?

Comment: Well its already there anyway (added **automatically**) - so adding it manually wont change the index, just remove the warning.